# What is the name of the part that allows a steam wand to have a moveable joint?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, steam, piping

On espresso machines, there is some kind of pipe joint which allows the steam wand to move while maintaining its seal. What is this component called?

Comment: There may be different joints in use. Do you have a service or repair manual? Do you have a picture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called a "steam wand gasket". Technically, it's a ball-and-socket joint made out of two concave [PTFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytetrafluoroethylene) (Teflon) gaskets and an [EDPM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPDM_rubber) gasket for the seal.

There may be other designs too; I learned this by watching *[Saeco StarBucks Barista - How to Replace Steam Wand Seals and Gasket](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fulyy9A9CYw)* (YouTube video).